# How to create a map from model to Entity, and Entity to model, with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, automapper, crm, xrm

I have a model

```
class Account 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress1 { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to configure AutoMapper to somehow loop through each property on my class and map it to the correct Entity value.

I am able to make a converter with reflection myself:

```
public Entity ConvertToEntity()
{
    var propertyDict = typeof(Account).GetProperties()
      .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(x.Name, x.GetValue(typeof(Account))));
    var entity = new Entity();

    foreach (var prop in propertyDict) t[prop.Key] = prop.Value;

    return entity;
 }
```

But how can i achieve the same kind of functionality with AutoMapper's CreateMap?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.i-avington.com/Posts/Post/building-a-blog-redux-mapping-view-models-to-entities-using-automapper-part

Comment: Can you show your Entity class?

Comment: Standard CRM Entity class
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entity.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you create marker interface like

```
// marker interface
public interface ICrmBusinessObject { }

public class MyAccount : ICrmBusinessObject
{
  public string EmailAddress1 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can define custom mapper function to convert those:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
  cfg.CreateMap<ICrmBusinessObject, Entity>()
    .AfterMap((crmEntity, entity) =>
    {
      var type = crmEntity.GetType();
      var propertyDict = type.GetProperties()
        .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(x.Name.ToLowerInvariant(),
          x.GetValue(crmEntity)));

      foreach (var prop in propertyDict)
      {
        entity[prop.Key] = prop.Value;
      }
    });
});
```

And you can use mapper like:

```
var myEntity = new MyAccount { EmailAddress1 = "me@contosco.com" };
var convertedEntity = Mapper.Map<Entity>(myEntity);
// me@contosco.com
Console.Out.WriteLine(convertedEntity["emailaddress1"]);
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu - that link is not relevant; CRM Entity class has Attributes property that is essentially Dictionary<string,object> to which we want to serialize all properties of the business object; I fail to see how that would be possible without explicit configuration.

Comment: Maybe you should read that more carefully. And if the wording could be better, a PR is welcome.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu - CRM entity Attributes property is not Dictionary, Entity is not dynamic object; checkout https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg326811%28v%3dcrm.8%29
this is simply not possible in vanilla mapper - you have to define custom rule

Comment: Nobody said that. But clearly no reflection is necessary. AM can get the properties for you. It's easy to map that to the final object.